# How can I use a function like tf.TensorArray in Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I need to change code from tensorflow to pytorch. Is there a similar function like `tf.TensorArray`?

For example:

```
iou_mask = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=1, dynamic_size=True)
```

Comment: TensorArray is mostly just a list of tensors. try `iou_mask=[]`, and then append items as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I set the tensor type and size but i dont know how to set dynamic size `iou_mask = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(1)`